Questions regarding the creation of sentient animals
This answer peaked my interest into the origins of sentient animals in Ramayanam and Mahabhartam respectively. I always thought that the entire species of Apes and Monkeys were created sentient and somehow lost their sentiency. But, from this it uses the term resemble. So did nonsentient bears and monkeys also exist in Mahabharta and the Devas were just excercising their creative power? Also, regarding Jambavan did he produce human offspring?
